# Transparent PNG not coming as transparent inside <div> tag

Tags: html, css

Here's an example I am trying:

```html
 <div class=red>
    
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/huxFtq5.png" width=50%>
    
    </div>
    
    <style>
    
    .red
    {
        border: 1px #BC8000 solid;
        background: #FDF5E5;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    </style>
```

The output is:

[image]

My question is how to make image transparent? The div background should stay 'yellow'.

**Update:** I am using a markdown software where I embed the HTML along with CSS. Could it be the software itself or, is there a way to tweak HTML?

Comment: Clearly not actually a transparent png. Just because it is a png doesn't mean it is automatically transparent.

Comment: It is transparent. See the link: https://i.imgur.com/huxFtq5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a class to your image or style it directly as inline css with a transparent background color. Some browsers may accidentally put a white or black BG Color on img.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .red {
            border: 1px #BC8000 solid;
            background: yellow;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=red>
        <img style="background-color: transparent;" src="https://i.imgur.com/huxFtq5.png" width=50%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixed the problem!

Comment: @user963241 Glad to know it helped!

Answer (score -1):

```css
.red{
  border: 1px #BC8000 solid;
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=red>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/huxFtq5.png" width=50%>
</div>
```